# how to set background image layer same trasparent color on image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-palette

I am new to Android. How to set a layer transparent color above the image using palette API. I set background image and toolbackground color using palette API but how to set above the background image transparent color picking from palette API? Any one please help me how to get this.

Here below my code

Main.java

```
  final LinearLayout mMainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.revi_main_layout);

    target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            mMainLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
            Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    movie_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    int defaultColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor);
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor(defaultColor));

                    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(palette.getDarkMutedColor(defaultColor));
                    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_news_update_fulldec));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load((Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos)).getNewsImage()).into(target);
```

Comment: what you need ?transparent color layer on imageview?

Comment: i need transparent color on every image using palette api i had multi images it load from server @RaviVGHL

Comment: fr image loading purpose i using picasso lib

Comment: https://github.com/florent37/PicassoPalette

Comment: actual i did that how to set trasparent color on above my background image@RaviVGHL